# Laravel, как проверить данные перед сохранением

Tags: laravel, request

У меня есть проект, структура таблиц ниже:

```
users
channels
 categories
  products
```

Где каналы относятся к пользователям, а категории относятся к каналам.
я хочу проверить перед при обновлении записи, принадлежит ли эта категория текущему пользователю.

Как мне проверить принадлежит ли категория пользователю или каналу перед обновлением в UpdateCategoryRequest?

```
class CategoryUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
   
    public function authorize()
    {
        $category = $this->route('category');
        $channel = Channel::where('id', $category->channel_id)
            ->first();
        if ($this->user()->id !== $channel->user_id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Сделал ли я это так правильно?

Comment: Это больше идеологический и архитектурный вопрос, чем технический. Да, можете так. Можете напрямую в контроллере/сервисе вызвать exception при проверке (грязнее, но работать будет), можете middleware создать на принадлежность категории каналу/пользователю. Выбор за Вами.

Comment: Vladimir Gonchar, спасибо за расширенное пояснение, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно как бы вы реализовали такую задачу архитектурно?